# Getting a div's background image with jQuery. Is there an inbuilt method to strip out the url() portion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to get the background image of a `div`.

```
var bgImage = $('#content').css('backgroundImage');
```

This is returning `url%28http://example.com/images/layout/content-trans.png%29`

I know you can do `element.height()` to get an element's height without `px` appended (`parseInt()` also works), so I was wondering if there was a similiar method for jQuery to get the actual background image minus the `url()` meta data.

I suppose I could use a regular expression, something like `/url\((.*)\)/`, but I'd rather know first if there is an built-in way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

url() is part of the value of background-image, so I guess you need to use regex replace.

```
var bgImage = $('#content').css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');
```

Ref: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/d866997cb206b35f

Comment: Regex it is then! Thank you! +1

Comment: Awesome, needed this for a mootools class.  Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes there will be " or ' attached so, adding /^url|[\(\)\"\']/g might help...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var imgUrl = 'http://example.com/images/layout/image.png';
var i = imgUrl.lastIndexOf("/"); 
var filename = imgUrl.substring(i, imgUrl.length - 1);
alert(filename);
```

In pure JS terms

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but is `string filename` legal in JavaScript?

Comment: @alex - hehe, nope. Wow, forgot about this one :)

Answer (score 0):

how about this easy solution:

```
bgImage.slice(bgImage.lastIndexOf('/')+1, bgImage.length - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = /url\(\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\1\s*\)/g.exec(str)[2];
```

Taken from the [waitForImages jQuery plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/blob/master/src/jquery.waitforimages.js#L67). I'm also the author.