# can't get background image with jquery in IE the value is about:blank 

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm trying to get the background image of the div and afterwards to change it by adding gray prefix to the bg image name.

Everything is working perfectly in chrome and firefox, but in IE the value of background image is `about-blank`. Please help me?

```
var img= $("#nom_"+$(".nomination").attr('id')).css('background-image');
            var image = img.split('/').pop();
            var img1 = image.split(')',1);
            var img1 = "<|UP>/gray"+img1;
```

the attr('id') is visible in IE the problem is with `.css('background-image')`;
but for IE I've changed it to

```
                    if($.browser.msie){
                        var id ="nom_"+$(".nomination").attr('id');
                        obj=document.getElementById(id);
                        alert(obj.currentStyle.backgroundImage);
                    }
```

but again the returned value is 'about-blank'.

Comment: Can you supply a URL or a jsfiddle?  It's very difficult to help with only a small part of the overall code. My initial guess would be that the background image isn't set when you try to get the value, but without more code it's not possible to tell. __Edit__: Okay, so it's not that, now that you've updated the question, so seeing the page in question would really help.

Comment: This works in Chrome, Firefox _and_ IE... http://jsfiddle.net/vL9kQ/  Something else is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes @Archer here is ok... I've try it with IE it gives me the URL... but in my website I have a fancybox witch loads a page... in that same  Loaded page I have the javascript witch is not working in ie... I'm calling the click function with .live() event but again nothing changes... (((

Comment: Can you supply the URL?  It would really help to be able to see the code and run some commands on the page manually.

Comment: ok archer Just a second i will upload the changes to show the alert value

Comment: no mate, the page URL so we can see the issue in action.

Comment: ok Archer the URL is [link](http://demo.softty.net/nom/) cklick to any circle and than to any green button then the url will appear... and than try with ie

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14063/discussion-between-encoder-and-archer)

Comment: Sorry mate - not got time atm to go into chat.  Also, I can't help since the circles don't work for me at all in IE.

Answer (score 0):

ok man...
Now the problem is solved...
As the problem was because of style attribute ...
When the background image is set by style (inline)
the `img= $("#nom_"+$(".nomination").attr('id')).css('background-image');` is not working in IE... but We can get it by changing this line with

```
var img= $("#nom_"+$(".nomination").attr('id')).attr('style');
                            var image = img.split('/').pop();
                            var img1 = image.split(')',1);
                            img1 = "<|UP>/gray"+img1;
```

in this case it is visible for IE...
and I'm able to add prefix to final img1 variable... 
thanks to everyone... )))

Answer (score -1):

I think that in the first example it should be:

.css('backgroundImage');

Comment: when using quotes you use the correct css name.  It's when you don't use quotes that you remove the hyphens as you describe.

Comment: No maaaaaaaan... that was a good idea... but again the value is about-blank... but don't think that the problem is related with dome as I am able to get the element id...

Comment: This thread might help you out if you haven't seen it already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837694/getting-a-divs-background-image-with-jquery-is-there-an-inbuilt-method-to-stri

Comment: dear @BillyMoat the problem is that background image value is about-blank if I get the value it is not a problem to change split it... But thanks for suggestion...)))