# How to get inline style that was overridden by CSS !important using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div style="background: url(http://www.example.com/image.jpg) center center/cover;">
```

This inline background image gets overridden by an external stylesheet:

```
div {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

My question: using JavaScript/jQuery, how can I get the URL of the background image that was defined in the inline styling but was overridden by CSS?

**Edit:** Trying to use `.css()` won't work because that gets the computed background style, which is `none`

Comment: I saw an answer for this in another SO question. Forgot where.

Comment: @Manu Nopes. I checked it. This is different.

Comment: try this var bg = $("div").css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');

Comment: Check out my answer now... `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Regex :

```
var match = $('div').attr('style').match(/url\(["|']?(.+)["|']?\)/);
var url = match ? match[1] : 'default.jpg';
```

Explanation :

`["|']?` will allow you to have quotes or not.
`(.+)` will *capture* the url to recover.

On the second line, we check that there is a match, and if there is none, return a default url.

Comment: Can I ask, why have you escaped `"` and `'`? I didn't think they had a meaning in regular expressions?

Comment: @BinaryFunt You're right! They don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Also, I think making the `(.+)` into `(.+?)` is required, otherwise a quote mark could be left on the end? PS nice and simple answer btw!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it this way:

```
function getStyle() {
  styles = $("div").attr("style");
  styles = styles.split(";");
  for (i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
    styles[i] = styles[i].replace(new RegExp(/http(.*)\:\/\//), "http$1___//");
    styles[i] = styles[i].split(":");
    styles[i][1] = styles[i][1].replace(/___/g, ":");
    if (styles[i][0].trim().indexOf("background") === 0)
      return styles[i][1].replace(/^(.*)url|[\(\)]/g, '').split(" ", 1)[0];
  }
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  alert($("div").css("background-image"));
  alert(getStyle());
});

function getStyle() {
  styles = $("div").attr("style");
  styles = styles.split(";");
  for (i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
    styles[i] = styles[i].replace(new RegExp(/http(.*)\:\/\//), "http$1___//");
    styles[i] = styles[i].split(":");
    styles[i][1] = styles[i][1].replace(/___/g, ":");
    if (styles[i][0].trim().indexOf("background") === 0)
      return styles[i][1].replace(/^(.*)url|[\(\)]/g, '').split(" ", 1)[0];
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: url(http://www.example.com/image.jpg) center center/cover;">
```

**Note:** The `$('div').css('background-image');` will always give the computed value of `none`.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery css method to get the DIV's background-image:

```
var bg = jQuery('div').css('background-image');
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar elaborate please

Comment: I looked around a little, I think this question might have been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837694/getting-a-divs-background-image-with-jquery-is-there-an-inbuilt-method-to-stri

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio That question is different because the background is not being overridden. Your answer here gets the computed background, which is `none` due to the stylesheet